# ChildNodes/NodeValue Confusion

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, nodevalue

I'm new with Ajax.

I'm trying to parse [this document](http://blanchardscoffee.com/xml/clientList.xml).

I've gotten as far as the readystatechange, and it's fetching the XML. But I get confused when it comes to the childNodes and their values.

Here's a bit of the code. If I try to alert that first value, it comes up blank.

```
var clientList = request.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('client');
for (var i=0;i<clientList.length;i++) {
    var client=clientList[i];
    var clientName = client.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    alert(clientName)
```

As far as I understand it, based on the XML document, each "client" tag would have the following ChildNodes:

```
[0] : clientName, 
[1] : clientStreetAddress, 
[2] : clientCity
[n] : ...and so on...
```

So what am I missing here? Clearly I don't have my facts straight. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You should read the data from the XML using the names of the tags, not based on what order they happen to be. When the document is parsed it might contain textnodes for the whitespace between the elements, which would offset the indexes of the elements containing the data that you want.

```
var clientName = client.childNodes.selectSingleNode('./clientName').nodeValue;
```

Comment: Alternatively, use something like [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) or jQuery to parse the XML document.

Comment: Ah. Okay. I assumed that the [0] was because it was returning the nodes and their contents as an array. I'll try that instead!

Comment: Well, I don't understand why, but it didn't work. It now doesn't even return a blank alert, meaning something in that is throwing an error of some sort.

Comment: TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'getElementsByTagName'

Comment: @Tom Thorogood: Right, that only works in the document object, use `selectSingleNode` instead. I updated the code in the answer.

Comment: TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'selectSingleNode' /grin. Man. And TeslaNick, I'm trying to figure out Xpath also. Either way I'd like to understand what's going on with this one too.

Comment: TeslaNick: I tried the following: var clientDoc = request.responseXML; var clientName = clientDoc.evaluate("data/client[1]/clientName", clientDoc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null); alert(clientName); and it displayed "undefined".

Comment: Update. I was trying, for some reason alert(ClientName.nodeValue) - trying just alert(clientName) returns "Object Xpath Result). That's progress, but I don't know how to get the actual string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to TeslaNick for suggesting I use XPATH instead. The answer was as follows:

```
var clientDoc = request.responseXML;
var clientName = clientDoc.evaluate("data/client[1]/clientName", clientDoc, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue
```

Of course, I think this has to be modified to handle IE browsers, and the path has to be set to loop through the clients. However, the actual, simplest answer is above.

Thanks also to Guffa for helping!